# What happened to the Salesforce API Explorer?

Tags: api

Two years ago or so we had the amazing Salesforce API Explorer that made it easy e.g. non-Salesforce developers to explore the REST API. It was so incredibly helpful and now we're back to the stone age - reading 500-page API docs again.

What happened? Did they remove it? Will it come back? I cannot find a single piece of information about this.

It had such nice links and looked really nice too:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/Account

[image: REST API Explorer - Account]

Comment: I even found a video that does not load anymore: https://www.salesforce.com/video/1110908/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open source [Postman Collection](https://github.com/forcedotcom/postman-salesforce-apis) available in GitHub. This unofficial collection currently holds close to 230+ API call templates for 10 Salesforce APIs (REST, Bulk, UI, Tooling, Metadata and Composite just to name a few).

This is a postman collection and not a OpenAPI Specification. But you can connect to a Salesforce Org and test it out.

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/03/explore-the-salesforce-apis-with-a-postman-collection

Comment: This is closer to what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at https://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php?

Some of the tools have been retired that are now part of Mulesoft.

Comment: Yes. It's okay-ish. But it's nowhere near what the API Explorer could do - or any modern REST API Explorer for that matter.